# PHP date and Zend_Date conversion?

Tags: php, date, zend-framework, formatting

I've got this date :

```
$date = 'Mon Feb 07 00:00:00 CST 2011';
```

But I want $date to be formatted as 02-07-2011 only, using Zend framework or core php also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('Mon Feb 07 00:00:00 CST 2011');

echo $date->format('m-d-Y');
```

Comment: thanku .but i have small doubt. If $date='Mon Feb 07 00:00:00 CST 2011'; i am using explode function i am getting $date=07,$month=Feb and $year=2011  this time how to convert using zend and core php explain me.

Comment: What is your doubt? it outputs `02-07-2011`

Comment: my output is 02-07-20011. how convert $date,$month and $year how to convert using zend and core php

Comment: That's very unusual. According to PHP docs Y => 'A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits'

Comment: if some times .it will come that time what should i do .

Comment: It shouldn't ever come up like that, and if it does its a bug in php.

Answer (score 4):

```
$date='Mon Feb 07 00:00:00 CST 2011';
echo date('m-d-Y',strtotime($date));
```

Working example at http://codepad.org/gYfgYqED